# Bar chart with line graph

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Looking to combine two visuals into a single graphic in python much like you can combine in R. I'm running into issues with it actually combining.

Using pandas and seaborn packages I have a dataframe of some hockey stats that I want to overlay two views as a visual *analysis*.

Sample of the data below:

| player | position | gp | g | a | tp | ppg | pim |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nikita Kucherov | RW | 68 | 33 | 52 | 85 | 1.25 | 38 |
| Steven Stamkos | C/W | 57 | 29 | 373 | 66 | 1.16 | 22 |
| Alex Killorn | LW | 68 | 26 | 23 | 49 | 0.72 | 20 |

I wanted a stacked bar chart of goal types (pph, a, g) and then an overlay of a line chart for penalized minutes (pim)

Here is the code I've tried most recently and it just gives me two separate visuals.

```
lightning2022top.plot(x="player", y=["ppg", "a", "g"], kind="bar", stacked = True,figsize=(15,10))
lightning2022top.plot(x="player",y = "pim", secondary_y = True)
plt.show()
```

UTFG has yet to show a concise example of how to combine like I would in ggplot with R. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pandas plots return ax, this can be accomplished by adding ax to the second graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df.plot(x="player", y=["ppg", "a", "g"], kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(8,6))
df.plot(x="player", y="pim", kind='line', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate flagged, but acceptable.